# Will blocking my IP address in Google Analytics will affect Google Search Console search analytics?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console, google-search, ip-address

I block my IP in Google Analytics so as it will not count visitors from our IP address.

I used to search through Google and click on our website from search results. to see if these actions are taken note by Google Webmaster Tools. I completed all sort of keywords that is related to my website and opened it from search results. But still I can't find the keywords in Google Search Console which I searched through Google and visited my website.

If we block IP in Google analytics, Will it also affect the report in Google Webmaster Tools ??

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, these are two separate systems. After all, in order to get GSC data into GA you have to create a connection between them. This would mean that normally, without a link, no data will (should?) be exchanged between them. Personally, I would be very surprised if indeed filters in GA would affect the data shown in GSC.

However, if you do keep having trouble logging data into GSC from your IP, try:

- Using a different IP address, for instance by utilizing a VPN or Tor.
- Try using a different browser, perhaps a browser plugin is messing things up
- Logout and login to your Google account

Comment: Why exact result is not shown in GSC.
It should show the search phrases which used to find my website and clicked on it right ?

Comment: Yes it should, but I wouldn't count on that number to be an exact one. For instance, if you read this blog then you will see many irregularities: https://moz.com/blog/google-search-console-webmaster-tools-reliability

Comment: These are two separate systems. Of course. You know that! Natively, GA has no idea about search performance and GSC knows nothing about users. The sources of data between the two are completely different. This is why the two have to be connected. The system does not make assumptions. And since GSC takes about 1 month to start making sense, no one should expect much for a while when new to the game. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your site at least one month old, so it obvious to get impression if your site indexed and got few backlinks.

Now if you link your GSC to GA it will only show the keywords that have at least 100 monthly search volume (from my experience). If it come from different keywords and not showing organic keywords in GA then it might be a Google crawler or third party crawler. And in common sense blocking IP in GA won't hurt your SEO.